# Howto scale thousands of bitcoin accounts properly with bitcoind deamon?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, e-wallet, bitcoin-core-accounts, scalability

It is said in the [bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Accounts_explained) that:

> The accounts code does not scale up to thousands of accounts with tens of thousands of transactions, because by-account (and by-account-by-time) indices are not implemented.
>   So many operations (like computing an account balance) require accessing every wallet transaction.

so my question is, what solution would be acceptable to implement a program who would be in charge of thousands of account (like an e-wallet).

My first guess would be to run multiple bitcoind instances, in order to keep the account by daemon ratio under a certain limit.

Any other idea ?

Comment: Don't use accounts and use database rows instead?

Answer (score 1):

Several options:

- Don't use bitcoind
- Use bitcoind to interface the p2p network but ignore accounts and other abstractions
- Hack bitcoind to use by-account indices